# Wordpress Shortcode in custom field within custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

Hi Guys Need help with this very badly.

Need to add shortcode to output in the area circled in white in the picture below.

And the input area is under video description. And from my understanding ive have confirmed that the name for that text area is description_value.

I have looked through every documentation and tried all filters and do_shortcode variations to no avail. Please help i have spent 3 days non stop doing this. Puting the codes in my function.php and so many others. It still does not parse [shortcodes] it just displays text "[shortcodes]". please refer to picture below

Thank you.

This is outputing on the page. I have

```
<div class="describe-feat">[postexpirator]</div>
```

This is in a file called grid-gallery.js

```
<h2><%= item.title %></h2></div><div class="view-gallery">\
                <div class="describe-feat"><%=item.desc%></div>\
                <% if(item.imgnum){ %><span class="item-num"><%= item.imgnum %></span><% } %>\
```

This is in custom post editor in wordpress admin area

```
<textarea name="description_value" class="option-textarea">[postexpirator]</textarea>
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/almn09e1dwmeywb/shortcodxe.jpg

Comment: Have you tried do_shortcode?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Answer (score 1):

It's because, you are missing `do_shortcode` function for parsing shortcode.

Assuming you just want to target a single value, you could just do this inside the loop.

```
<?php echo ( do_shortcode( get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'Your textarea Key Name' , true ) ) ); ?>
```

If your post has multiple values for that custom field, then you can set the above to false.. and loop over the array...

```
<?php $values = do_shortcode( get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'Your textarea Key Name' , false ) ); ?>
<?php if($values && is_array($values)) : ?>
<?php foreach( $values as $meta) : ?>
<p><?php echo $meta ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi @phpdeveloper. In 3 days i went through almost 30 sites and read more then 100 posts. I still dont understand what is going on.Your answer was tried before- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/allowing-shortcode-in-custom-fields.

But how do i make sure the code runs correctly where do i put it. Do i put in functions.php do i put in in the theme file that the page will load? because i tried all that and it is still not parsing the shortcode. I replaced 'your textarea key name' to description_value. Is this correct? Thank you so much for your help if you could help me i can finally die happy

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that if you won't use the_post() no shortcode will work,
I had this issue when trying to enable shortcode on CutomFields on a new page type, and nothing worked  until activating WP loop with the_post() .